# Return all enum items as a TStringList

Tags: delphi, enums, tstringlist, typeinfo

My function `EnumToStringList()` on its own can be compiled, but I can't call it with any enum type in my app:

> [dcc64 Error] Unit_test.pas(119): E2029 '(' expected but ')' found

What is wrong with my approach?

```pascal
function EnumToStringList(const TypeInfo: pTypeInfo): TStringlist;
var  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  for i := GetTypeData(TypeInfo)^.MinValue to GetTypeData(TypeInfo)^.MaxValue do
    begin
      result.add (GetEnumName(TypeInfo, i));
    end;
end;
        
function EnumToString(const TypeInfo: pTypeInfo; Ix: Integer): string;
begin
  result := GetEnumName(TypeInfo, Ix);
end;
    
type
  TProjectTypes = (low,hot,skip,pause,others);

// test code:
MyProjectStrings := EnumToStringList (TProjectTypes);
```

Comment: copy & paste issue or do you have really ":" `others):` here?

Comment: what delphi version?

Comment: and you are working somehwere with `low` and you redefine it in your `TProjectTypes`

Comment: TProjecttypes  = (hot, veryhot, untiltomorrow) ;  that's the view  of my boss  :-)

Comment: Please put more effort into code & text formatting - there's no consistency and nobody knows where in your excerpt line 119 is supposed to be. After all the years you should have more sense for all this. Judging from how your code looks (too many or no spaces at all, indentions at will) you're just not paying attention to details.

Comment: `type TProjectType = (ptLow, ptHot, ptSkip, ptPause, ptOther)` is the idiomatic approach. Please note that there is no plural *s* in the type name. Indeed, if `var ProjectType: TProjectType` then `ProjectType` very clearly is a single type, e.g. `ptLow`. Compare with other types: `var ProjectName: string; ProjectYear: Integer; ProjectType: TProjectType`, not `var ProjectName: strings; ProjectYear: Integers; ProjectType: TProjectTypes`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly pass enumeration type to your function. You need to get its type info first by calling `TypeInfo` on it.

```
  var
    MyProjectStrings := EnumToStringList(TypeInfo(TProjectTypes));
```

Comment: "*You cannot directly pass enumeration type to your function*" - you can if you make `EnumToStringList` be a Generic function, eg: `EnumToStringList<TProjectTypes>();` and then use `TypeInfo(T)` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
implementation

uses
  System.TypInfo;

procedure EnumToStringList (Sender: TObject);

type
  TProjectTypes = (low, hot, skip, pause, others);

var
  pt: TProjectTypes;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for pt := System.Low(TProjectTypes) to System.High(TProjectTypes) do
      sl.Add(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TProjectTypes), ord(pt)));

    ShowMessage(sl.Text);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

One guess: You work with `System.Low` at some point but you redefine `low` with your `TProjectTypes`. Just put a `System.` infront of your `Low`.