# Enumeration in Listbox, Radiogroup etc.... , find selected item only via index or ...?

Tags: delphi

I want to know the best coding style for editing an enumeration via `TListBox`, `TComboBox`, `TRadioGroup`, etc.

In [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77912908/), I already found a solution to convert my enumeration into a `TStringList` that I can then place into a `TComboBox`, `TRadioGroup`, etc and extract the select Enum/String item via the index, like:

```
///  get enum item via index of Radiogroup
enumitem  :=  TProjectType(TypeOfAnalysisRadioGroup.ItemIndex);
```

Is there any other/better option of selecting an enum item via a VCL GUI control?

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Why not use [DesignEditors.TEnumProperty](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/DesignEditors.TEnumProperty) instead as it probably already offers the functionality you desire. And if not you can always derive from it.

Comment: @SilverWarior You can't use the IDE's design-time code in runtime applications.

Comment: @Franz your approach only works for simple enums with sequential values starting at 0. But enums are more flexible than that.